# wirejs and dojo using the dojo build system (2)

Tags: dojo, wirejs, cujojs

(This is the same question as [wirejs and dojo using the dojo build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024573/wirejs-and-dojo-using-the-dojo-build-system), but with more detail about the problem and tried solutions. The duplicate question is created because this was suggested in a comment).

When building a dojo application that uses wire, the dojo loader throws an `undefinedModule` Error for "./lib/context" that we can't get rid of.

I added `wire` to a large, working dojo project using a git submodule. It turned out that also cujojs `when` and cujojs `meld` are required. I added them as a git submodule too.

In this project, libraries are not next to the application folder (`src/app`), but one level deep, in `src/lib`. So I have `src/lib/wire`, `src/lib/when`, `src/lib/meld`, next to `src/lib/dgrid`, etc. `dojo` libraries are 2 levels deep: `src/lib/dojo/dojo`, `src/lib/dojo/dijit`, `src/lib/dojo/dojox` and `src/lib/dojo/util`.

Versions:

- dojo 1.10.4
- wire 0.10.9
- when 3.7.2
- meld 1.3.1

Things work in development (unbuild) once I add the following package definitions to `dojoConfig`:

```
var dojoConfig = (function() {

  [...]

  return {

    [...]

    packages: [

      [...]

      {name: "wire", location: "../../wire", main: "wire"},
      {name: "when", location: "../../when", main: "when" },
      {name: "meld", location: "../../meld", main: "meld" },

      [...]

    ],

    [...]
  };

})();
```

Note that it was necessary to add the `main` entries. This makes it possible, e.g., to refer to `when/when.js` as just `"when"` in a dependency list, instead of `"when/when"`, which the cujojs code does internally.

So, this works in development mode.

Next, I tried to get the build working.

In the `build.profile.js`, I again added the package references. The build fails that way in a number of ways.

First, for packages, the dojo builder expects a `dojoBuild` property in the `package.json` files, that refers to a `<mypackage>.profile.js` or `package.js` file, that essentially defines the build configuration for the packages.
This build configuration is most often (it is in all our packages) just a `resourceTags` object, with functions that define what files are AMD resources in the package, what files are tests, and which should be copied as is.

The cujojs packages do not have such build definitions usable for the dojo builder.

The builder complains first that there is no build configuration for these packages, and secondly that resources are not flagged as AMD resources (which is the main reason of being for this build configuration files).

Since I do not want to change files of an external library I use, I am not inclined to add a `dojoBuild` property and build configuration file to the cujojs packages, so I sought a workaround.

After stepping through the dojo builder code, I found that the builder complains about a `package.json` file not having a `dojoBuild` property, but finally just looks at the internal package definition structure to get the `resourceTags` object. The internal package definition structure starts out with the package definition from the main build profile. So, I ended up piggy-backing a `resourceTags` object there:

```
[...]

/*
 wire, when and meld don't have a good build profile set up.
 Here, we doctor a resourceTags (i.e., the core of a build profile). We set it on the package definition.
 This is an unsupported hack. The builder will still complain about there not being a build profile, but
 it will use these definitions when building those packages.

 Note: // see https://github.com/cujojs/when/wiki/Using-with-Dojo does not work!
*/
var generalResourceTags = (function () {

  function isTest(filename, mid) {
    return filename.indexOf("test/") >= 0;
  }

  function isCopyOnly(filename, mid) {
    return filename.indexOf(".html") >= 0;
  }

  function isAmd(filename, mid) {
    return filename.indexOf(".json") < 0 && filename.indexOf(".js") >= 0 && filename.indexOf(".profile.js") < 0;
  }

  function isGivingTroubleButUnused(filename, mid) {
    return /^wire\/jquery\//.test(mid) ||
           mid === "wire/sizzle" ||
           /^when\/build\//.test(mid) ||
           /^when\/es6-shim\//.test(mid) ||
           mid === "when/generator"; // see https://github.com/cujojs/when/issues/429
  }

  return {
    test: function (filename, mid) {
      return isTest(filename, mid);
    },

    copyOnly: function (filename, mid) {
      return isCopyOnly(filename, mid) || isGivingTroubleButUnused(filename, mid);
    },

    amd: function (filename, mid) {
      return !isTest(filename, mid) && !isCopyOnly(filename, mid) && isAmd(filename, mid) && !isGivingTroubleButUnused(filename, mid);
    }
  }
})();

var profile = {
  releaseName: releaseName,
  releaseDir: "../../../../release",
  action: 'release',
  cssOptimize: 'comments',
  mini: true,
  optimize: 'closure',
  layerOptimize: 'closure',
  stripConsole: 'normal',
  selectorEngine: 'acme',
  useSourceMaps: false,

  [...]  

  packages: [

    [...]

    {name: "wire", location: "../../wire", main: "wire", destLocation: "./lib/wire", resourceTags: generalResourceTags},
    {name: "when", location: "../../when", main: "when", destLocation: "./lib/when", resourceTags: generalResourceTags},
    {name: "meld", location: "../../meld", main: "meld", destLocation: "./lib/meld", resourceTags: generalResourceTags},

    [...]

  ],
  layers: {

    [...]

  },
  staticHasFeatures: {
    "config-publishRequireResult": false,
    "dijit-legacy-requires": false,
    "dojo-debug-messages": false,
    "dojo-firebug": false,
    "dojo-log-api": 0,
    "dojo-mobile-parser": false,
    "dojo-moduleUrl": false,
    "dojo-parser": true,
    "dojo-publish-privates": 0,
    "dojo-test-sniff": 0,
    "dojo-trace-api": 0,
    "dom-addeventlistener": true,
    "extend-dojo": true,
    "host-browser": true,
    "mvc-bindings-log-api": false,

    [...]

  }
};
```

Note the extra `resourceTags` property in the package definitions for `wire`, `when` and `meld`. I kept things "simple", and just used one general object to handle all 3 cases, `generalResourceTags`. This is a pretty standard `resourceTags` setup, apart from `isGivingTroubleButUnused`, which I'll get to in a moment.

Note that I tried the solution mentioned explicity at https://github.com/cujojs/when/wiki/Using-with-Dojo for `when`, and that it *did not work*.

This way, we get a pretty decent report from the dojo builder, but it mentions some missing resources. E.g., some modules require jquery. But, those modules aren't used in this project.

Note that the solution mentioned in [wirejs and dojo using the dojo build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024573/wirejs-and-dojo-using-the-dojo-build-system), piggy-backing `packageJson` might be better. I haven't tested it.

I ended up introducing the `isGivingTroubleButUnused` to copy these modules without handling them, as we don't use them anyway. Note that 1 of the issues is in `when/generator`. The Closure compiler sees a syntax error there (see https://github.com/cujojs/when/issues/429).

The net result of this setup is a build without errors.

And then, we want to test this ... and it fails. The first error we get is indeed the dojo loader throwing an `undefinedModule` `Error` for `"./lib/context"`. The only place this occurs in indeed on line 23 of `wire/wire.js`:

```
createContext = require('./lib/context');
```

This is intended to resolve to `wire/lib/context.js`, and obviously this works in development (unbuild) mode.

In any case, `require` is intended to be a context-sensitive require (see dojotoolkit.org /documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules_advanced/, "Conditionally requiring modules"), as the module reference is relative. But that should be no reason why it works unbuild, and doesn't work build.

Next, I tried to just copy all the `wire`, `when` and `meld` resources. If a resource is not included in the dojo build of a layer, it just falls back to async loading. So, this could work:

```
var generalResourceTags = (function () {

  function isTest(filename, mid) {
    return filename.indexOf("test/") >= 0;
  }

  [...]

  return {
    test: function (filename, mid) {
      return isTest(filename, mid);
    },

    copyOnly: function (filename, mid) {
      return !isTest(filename, mid);
    },

    amd: function (filename, mid) {
      return false;
    }
  }
})();
```

The build now passes, and copies what is needed. There are more errors, of course, where the app code reference `wire`, but that is to be expected (`error(311) Missing dependency. module: MY_MODULE; dependency: wire!SOME_PACKAGE/_wire-serverRequests`).

Yet, the browser gives the same error, in the same place: an `undefinedModule` `Error` for `"./lib/context"`.

The working hypothesis at this point that the function used by `wire` under the name `require` is not a context-sensitive require in the build version, but is in the unbuild version.

This is not true. First, I changed the `wire` code or a test to read

```
createContext = require('wire/lib/context');
```

making the reference absolute. Same problem.

Then, I tried to debug using sourceMaps (`useSourceMaps = true`). This is a nightmare, but I believe I see that the `require` used is the same, the context-sensitive require.

Maybe "preloading" works? So, in the top HTML page, I surrounde all code with

```
require(["wire/lib/context"], function() {

  [...]

});
```

This makes sure `context` is loaded before we do anything else. Same error.

Next, I added logging to the code in `wire/lib/context`

```
console.error("Defining context");

var when, mixin, loaderAdapter, relativeLoader, Container, specUtils;

when = require('when');
console.error("Loaded when");
mixin = require('./object').mixin;
console.error("Loaded ./object");
loaderAdapter = require('./loader/adapter');
console.error("Loaded ./loader/adapter");
relativeLoader = require('./loader/relative');
console.error("Loaded ./loader/relative");
Container = require('./Container');
console.error("Loaded ./Container");
specUtils = require('./specUtils');

console.error("Defined context. Returning.");
```

(using `error`, because other messages are stripped in the build).

In the unbuild version, I see all messages. In the build version, I see only "Defining context" before the error occurs. So the problem is not with "loading" `wire/lib/context`, but in defining it, and probably in loading or defining `when`!

So, I applied to same trick to `when`

```
console.error("Defining when");

var timed = require('./lib/decorators/timed');
console.error("Loaded lib/decorators/timed");
var array = require('./lib/decorators/array');
console.error("Loaded lib/decorators/array");
var flow = require('./lib/decorators/flow');
console.error("Loaded lib/decorators/flow");
var fold = require('./lib/decorators/fold');
console.error("Loaded lib/decorators/fold");
var inspect = require('./lib/decorators/inspect');
console.error("Loaded lib/decorators/inspect");
var generate = require('./lib/decorators/iterate');
console.error("Loaded lib/decorators/iterate");
var progress = require('./lib/decorators/progress');
console.error("Loaded lib/decorators/progress");
var withThis = require('./lib/decorators/with');
console.error("Loaded lib/decorators/with");
var unhandledRejection = require('./lib/decorators/unhandledRejection');
console.error("Loaded lib/decorators/unhandledRejection");
var TimeoutError = require('./lib/TimeoutError');
console.error("Loaded lib/TimeoutError");
[...]
```

Now there is a surprise in the **unbuild** version. The output is:

```
Defining when
Loaded lib/decorators/timed
Loaded lib/decorators/array
Loaded lib/decorators/flow
Loaded lib/decorators/fold
Loaded lib/decorators/inspect
Loaded lib/decorators/iterate
Loaded lib/decorators/progress
Loaded lib/decorators/with
Loaded lib/decorators/unhandledRejection
Loaded lib/TimeoutError
Loaded lib/Promise
Loaded lib/apply
Defined when
Defining context
Loaded when
Loaded ./object
Loaded ./loader/adapter
Loaded ./loader/relative
Loaded ./Container
Defined context. Returning.
```

Which means `when` definition started *before* `context` definition. This is weird, because I see no code that can tell the loader that `when` is required in `context`, before the line

```
when = require('when');
```

is executed, which comes *after* the logging of "Defining context".

In the build version, we still only get

```
Defining context
```

before the error occurs! This behaviour is clearly different!

Next, I removed the preloading code. Unbuild code gives the same output, build code now has *no* messages before the error occurs.

So in any case, this `wire` code is doing things I don't expect and understand during loading.

I do hope this extra detail will trigger someone to get us on the right track ...

Comment: Logged as an issue at https://github.com/cujojs/wire/issues/168

Comment: try turning on factory scanning in dojo's build in your profile set `factoryScan: 1` in order for the build to find that wire uses './lib/context' when you run it.

Comment: also, inlining `resourceTags` in your build profile is not a hack but is indeed a way that dojo's builder is intended to be used.  it was expected that you may try to use packages that don't include a `dojoBuild` property in their package.json so inlining is supported for this exact reason.

Comment: I would add to that that I created a separate build profile for each wire package (wire, meld, poly and when), then I declare them in my main build profile in the packages array, as follows : {   name : 'wire', location : packagesDir + '/wire', main : 'wire',  packageJson : { dojoBuild : 'path/to/my/profiles/wire.profile.js' }}

Comment: btw, a mix of excluding the problematic resources in my profiles and using factoryScan : 1 seems to allow me to do a build. I'll try to set up a skeleton project to test and share it on github...